# Find all roots of a polynomial using secant method

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I am writing a program that will find **all** zeros of a polynomial using secant method. But this method despite my best efforts doesn't always converge.

How to find the initial value for the secant method such that it will converge?

Comment: Did you consider that a polynomial may have complex roots (is that what the nan-detection is for?)? That the failure sources of Newton's method translate to similar problems in the secant method? You might get better results with restarting at random values if an iteration takes too long.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's little help: You are facing a fundamental problem there. Finding points from which the secant method will converge towards the roots (even ignoring the degenerate case of multiple roots) is the hard part of root finding. Or put differently, the state of the art is that you can only guarantee that the secant method (or Newton's method, or Aberth-Ehrlich/Börsch-Supan's method, or Durand-Weierstraß-Kerner, or...) converges for approximations which are chosen close enough to the roots that the problem is essentially already solved.

If you want a complete algorithm, go for subdivision approaches (e.g., methods based on Descartes' rule of signs); if you are happy with an easy-to-implement and fast algorithm that always works in practice, use Aberth-Ehrlich for all complex roots and filter out the real ones. Or just use the already existing libraries such as Fabrice Rouillier's [RS](http://vegas.loria.fr/rs/) (real roots) or Bini and Robol's [MPSolve](https://github.com/robol/MPSolve) (complex).

IIRC, there are results which guarantee the convergence of individual Newton-like methods towards all roots if "enough" starting points are chosen (where "enough" is polynomial in the degree of your input) according to a certain distribution. But again, it is non-trivial to implement that, and AFAIK it only works for complex roots where you know in advance that there are exactly degree many roots. This serves as a criterion to know when to stop iterating over the remaining guesses.